# Initialising array and constructor not working

Tags: java, oop, parameters, constructor

I want to call the constructor ConcreteSubject in the ConcreteSubject class to main. I am trying to create an array along with a constructor which accepts in as parameters to initalise the array. So i'm not sure what's missing/wrong.

```
public class ConcreteSubject extends AbstractSubject {
    public int arySize;

    private AbstractSpy[] spies;

    public ConcreteSubject(int a) {
        arySize = a;
        spies = new AbstractSpy[a];
    }

    @Override
    void notifySpies() {

    }

    @Override
    public void addSpy(AbstractSpy spy) {

    }
}

public class TestSpies {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this is where there is something wrong as it whats another constructor created.
        ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject();
        AbstractSpy spy = new ConcreteSpy();
        AbstractSpy[] spies = new AbstractSpy[10];
        cs.addSpy(spy);
    }
}
```

Comment: You gave your class a constructor that takes an `int a` as a parameter and therefor also have to call the constructor with that parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you create constructor for your class the java does not give you the default constructor. and you ae intialising your object with  ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject();

there are 2 solution to initialise the array:

1. create a default constructor in your class ConcreteSubject

   public ConcreteSubject() {

   ```
   }
   ```

and then intiaise array `

```
cs.arySize= x //whatever value you want`
cs.spies = new new AbstractSpy[a];
```

2. or you have to  intialise your object like below:

   ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject(x); //whatever value you want

Answer (score 3):

You defined your constructor as below, having an int parameter :

```
public ConcreteSubject(int a) {
…
}
```

Which means that when you call it you need to pass an int parameter, eg :

```
ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

ConcreteSubject class doesn't have default constructor. There is only one constructor with int param:

```java
public ConcreteSubject(int a) {
//    ...
}
```

And you have to pass `int` param to that constructor's call. 
So, the call should look like:

```java
int x = ...
new ConcreteSubject(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't create a constructer, java will create a default constructer automatically. But if you create one that is not default, like the one you created with the int parameter, then you'll have to create a default constructer by yourself (if you need it) because java will not make a default one in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can deal with this problem:

A. Create a non-parametrized constructor in `ConcreteSubject` class

```
public ConcreteSubject() {
    //Initialize the variables with default values
}
```

B. Or, use `ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject(10);` instead of `ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject();` in `main` method.